# Can not attach Aws Iot Policy with Certificate

Tags: android, aws-iot

```
 AttachPrincipalPolicyRequest policyAttachRequest = new AttachPrincipalPolicyRequest();
 policyAttachRequest.setPolicyName(AWS_IOT_POLICY_NAME);                            

 policyAttachRequest.setPrincipal(createKeysAndCertificateResult.getCertificateArn());                 
 mIotAndroidClient.attachPrincipalPolicy(policyAttachRequest);
```

Here I want to attach a policy with aws certificate in aws iot.
For this operation i'm using attachPrincipalPolicy() function.
But this function is depreacted in 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-iot:2.6.29' sdk version. 
so each time after certificate created i need to manually attach policy with certificate. 
Is there any other method for attach policy with aws Certificate?

Answer (score 1):

```
AWSIot awsIotClient = AWSIotClientBuilder.defaultClient();
awsIotClient.createPolicy(new CreatePolicyRequest().withPolicyDocument(policy).withPolicyName(policyName));
awsIotClient.attachPolicy(new AttachPolicyRequest().withPolicyName(policyName).withTarget("arn:aws:iot:<region>:<client_ID>:cert/<certificate_ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ref : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_AttachPrincipalPolicy.html

**AttachPrincipalPolicy**

> Attaches the specified policy to the specified principal (certificate
>   or other credential).
>
> Note: This API is deprecated. Please use [AttachPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_AttachPolicy.html) instead.

**Edit 2**

```
AttachPrincipalPolicyRequest attachPolicyReq = new AttachPrincipalPolicyRequest(); //in docs it called AttachPolicyRequest but it`s wrong
attachPolicyReq.setPolicyName("allAllowed"); //name of your IOTAWS policy
attachPolicyReq.setPrincipal(getIdRes.getIdentityId());
new AWSIotClient(credentialsProvider).attachPrincipalPolicy(attachPolicyReq);
```

For More Information
[AWS IoT Android application over MQTT throws MqttException (0) - java.io.IOException: Already connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244375/aws-iot-android-application-over-mqtt-throws-mqttexception-0-java-io-ioexcep)

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/issues/92

Comment: *I specified certificate here-->* `policyAttachRequest.setPrincipal(createKeysAndCertificateResult.getCertificateArn()); ` *And attach policy here-->*  `mIotAndroidClient.attachPrincipalPolicy(policyAttachRequest);`  But it is not working. The policy and certificate are there. but policy could not attach with certificate.