# AWSIotMqttManager: onFailure: connection failed. MqttException (0) - java.io.IOException: Already connected

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

I am currently developing a mobile application with Android Studio where this app should authenticate via AWS Cognito which I do with AWS Amplify. Amplify seems to be working fine but when I try to connect to the device shadow of my Greengrass thing, I get the error from the title of this question:

> AWSIotMqttManager: onFailure: connection failed.
> MqttException (0) - java.io.IOException: Already connected

It is rather strange since I should not be connected since I have not called the connect command yet.

Here is my code:

```
// Here I get the credentials which I later use to connect to AWSIoT    
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(), // get the context for the current activity
                "*****", // your AWS Account id
                "us-east-2:****************", // your identity pool id
                "arn:aws:iam::*************-unauthRole",// an authenticated role ARN
                "arn:aws:iam::*************-authRole", // an unauthenticated role ARN
                Regions.US_EAST_2 //Region
        );
    


        //Here I create the AWSIotMqttManager
        AWSIotMqttManager awsIotMqttManager = new AWSIotMqttManager(uuidAsString,"endpoint");
       
       //then I connect it
       try {
            awsIotMqttManager.connect(credentialsProvider, new AWSIotMqttClientStatusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(AWSIotMqttClientStatus status, Throwable throwable) {

                    if (status == AWSIotMqttClientStatus.Connected) {

                        awsIotMqttManager.subscribeToTopic("$aws/things/thing/shadow/update/documents", AWSIotMqttQos.QOS0, new AWSIotMqttNewMessageCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onMessageArrived(String topic, byte[] data) {
                                System.out.println("TOPIC: " + topic);
                                System.out.println(data);
                            }
                        });

                        String message = "{ \"state\": {\"desired\": {\"message\": \"Hello from ANDROID SDK\"} } }} }";
                        awsIotMqttManager.publishString(message,"$aws/things/thing/shadow/update",AWSIotMqttQos.QOS0);

                    }
                    
             
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("CHECK", e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: So what line triggers the error?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary `awsIotMqttManager.connect()` triggers the error.

Comment: Is this your full code? Please provide a a Minimal, Reproducible Example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Everything related to the connection, yes.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48856472/4800344

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary No, I already tried it.